# How to modify - data from backend in rxjs observable using pipe()?

Tags: angular7, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I am getting values from backend by using this method:

```
getCourse():Observable<ModelCourse[]> {
        return this.http.get<ModelCourse[]>(environment.baseUrl+"Course")
        .pipe(
            map(data => data.value ),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        )
    }
```

as per backend response my result is like this:

```
{"@odata.context":"https://sbiconfigservice.azurewebsites.net/api/$metadata#Calendar","value":[{"Id":1,"Title":"abcd","Start":"1/1/19","End":"31/12/19","AllDay":true,"ColorId":1}]}
```

now i am trying to return alone the `value` - as response. but getting error as `property value does not exiting on ModelCourse` - so how to return value alone using rxjs approach here?

[image: getting warring]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what type you specify in the get request.

It's an array when your backend response is actually an object, the **value** property within the response object is the array.

Comment: so, do you want to declare as array? can you update my code? I keep getting error as `ERROR in src/app/calendar/services/calendar.service.ts(23,25): error TS2551: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'ModelEvent[]'.` not able to compile the code...

Comment: The getCourse function returns the correct type of Observable. It's the actual get request that specifies an incorrect type, change it to this, http.get(any)(environemnt.baseUrl + "Course")

Comment: Unless you have a type interface for the actual response object, then yes this is the correct approach. This has more to do with your backend returning an object rather than an array of entities.